# How to Spring mvc receives the axios array？

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, vue.js, axios

In a brand controller class, I want to do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "brand",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object deleteByIds(int[] ids) {
    System.out.println(ids);
    goodsBrandService.deleteByIds(ids);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("msg","success to delete");
    return jsonObject;
}
```

**When receives the array,but it gives me null.**

I have mapping file：

```
<delete id="deleteByIds" parameterType="list">
    DELETE FROM
    goods_brand
    WHERE brand_id IN
  <foreach collection="array" item="item" open="(" separator="," close=")">
    ${item}
  </foreach>
```

I use axios on Vue.js to send params to Spring MVC,for example：

```
 // Determine bulk delete
 multiDelete() {
  let checkArr = this.multipleSelection;
  let params = [];
  let self = this;
  checkArr.forEach(function (item) {
    params.push(item.brandId); 
  });
  console.log(params); 
  this.$http.get('http://localhost:9090/brand', params).then(function (res) {
    if (res) {
      self.$message({
        message: 'success to delete',
        type: 'success'
      });
    }
  }).then(error => {
    this.$message.error("failed to delete");
  })
  this.multiDeleteVisible = false; //close delete bullet box
}
```

When axios is sent to, the chrome browser console print to `console.log(params)` ,for example :

```
(2) [43, 41]
    0: 43
    1: 41
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

**problem was in [] for parameter,How does Spring MVC accept the correct array?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "brand/{ids}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object deleteByIds(@PathVariable Integer[] ids) {
 System.out.println(ids);
 goodsBrandService.deleteByIds(ids);
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.put("msg","success to delete");
 return jsonObject;
}
```

---

I think it should be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "brand",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object deleteByIds(@RequestParam(value="ids[]") Integer[] ids) {

}
```

But I recommend to use `POST` method instead `GET`, so your request mapping changes to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "brand",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object deleteByIds(@RequestBody WarapperList ids) {

}
```

and `WrapperList` is a class like this:

```
class WrapperList{
    private List<Integer> ids;
}
```